# How to disable an event listener in mapbox?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, layer, mapbox-gl

I am trying to have control over event listeners over a layer with Mapbox on React.
map.off is supossed to do the trick, but it is not removing the onclick event in a layer. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#off

But I am doing something wrong so I can't manage to remove the event.
Here is what I have done so far...

To add the event I do this

`map.on('click', 'building_footprints_click', addBuildingPopUp)`

And to try to remove it I tried:

`map.off('click', 'building_footprints_click', addBuildingPopUp);`

`map.off('click', 'building_footprints_click');`

`map.off('click', addBuildingPopUp);`

But none of them are working.
I read that I have to send to off the instance of the on event. So I tried to:

`let event = map.on('click', 'building_footprints_click', addBuildingPopUp)`

and the same three off operations as above but they don't work either

`map.off('click', 'building_footprints_click', event);`

`map.off('click', 'building_footprints_click');`

`map.off('click', event);`

And also the listener function,
I have tried with:

```
const addBuildingPopUp = (e) => {} 

and 
function addBuildingPopUp (e) {} 

and 
let addBuildingPopUp = function building (e) {}
```

Here is a basic Stackblitz with a example of the non working function
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5maykf?file=src/App.js

https://react-5maykf.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Can u attach codepen or jsfiddle to replicate, also, are u sure you are passing same reference of function  addBuildingPopUP you have defined?

Comment: Here is a short version of it> 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5maykf?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 5):

Based on your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5maykf?file=src/App.js) I can see that the problem is that you are trying to deregister a function that no longer exists.

For mapbox you need to register and deregister the same function. I mean
`map.on('mousemove', f1)` and `map.off('mousemove', f1)` you need to ensure that f1 remains the same.

Let me explain that, whenever a react component renders, it does recreate all variables inside it's body unless it is part of a state variable, since the function `addBuildingPopUp` is created on every render mapboxgl does not deregister the event.

The only change you need to do is to ensure `addBuildingPopUp` remains the same, you should define outside React Component.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your stackblitz code and update the working answer accordingly with comments. Let me know if you have any questions on it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mqjjkg?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js

Comment: Is there a change to use useEffect with this approach? Because it is working but whenever I want to use the map in response to a variable with UseEffect change, it says map is still null. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9kts21?file=src/App.js

Comment: Hi @JorgeMonroy, Please note: useEffect fires on every state change state (according to the dependency array), Which was causing the actual problem and was creating new instance of addBuildingPopUp, removeEvent and re-instantiate  mapRenderer  variable to "null". I have updated the code again please check on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4e6kxg?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js and notice how the instance of mapbox-gl map and actual function definition are moved to top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Functions that you pass to the mapbox event Listener have to be exactly the same. Everytime a component renders in react, the function (although it stays the same) will be recognized by javascript as a new declared function. Therefore mapbox will "off" a listener, that doesn't event exist, because it's a function thats never been there. To solve it, you have to use React "useCallback". It ensures that functions remain the same over the course of the existence of the component

```
export default function MapListeners() {
  const mode = useRecoilValue(interactivityMode);
  const setModal = useSetRecoilState(modalState);

  const removeListeners = () => {
    cuMap.off("click", setAddBeaconModal);
  };

  const setAddBeaconModal = useCallback(
    // useCallback ensures the functions stays identical
    (e: mapboxgl.MapMouseEvent & mapboxgl.EventData) => {
      // const coordinates = e.lngLat;

      setModal({
        key: AddBeaconModal.toString(),
        body: {
          component: AddBeaconModal,
          props: { word: "irgendwas", title: "Irrr" },
        },
        title: "Add Beacon",
      });
    },
    []
  );

  const setMapListeners = () => {
    removeListeners();

    switch (mode) {
      case "add":
        cuMap.on("click", setAddBeaconModal);
        break;
      case "lock":
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  useEffect(setMapListeners, [mode]);

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use React, just store the handler(s) inside of useRef, and voila, everything will work, [here's the similar situation and a proposed solution](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/963#issuecomment-850224251)

Here's the code for the solution:

```
  const handleClickRef = useRef(handleClick)
  handleClickRef.current = handleClick
  map.on('mousedown', 'layer-id', handleClickRef.current)
  map.off('mousedown', 'layer-id', handleClickRef.current)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in React. I was trying for days to do this. So in my case I wanted to remove an on click listener which would add some custom markers. Here is how I did it (for testing):

`Attributes in File`

`const map = useRef(null);`

```
map.current.on('click', (event) => addMarkerOnClick(event));
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Disabled")
  map.current.off('click', (event) => addMarkerOnClick(event));
}, 5000)
```

**The above was how I had my code initially, it WONT work.**

```
    map.current.on('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Disabled")
      map.current.off('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    }, 5000)
```

**That's the solution ^**

For none React users, I suggest this:

```
// Attributes
let map = null

    map.on('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Disabled")
      map.off('click', addMarkerOnClick);
    }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll chip in as I had a similar problem this morning. The solution that I ended up taking was storing the function that I was passing to map.on and map.off inside a useCallback hook with empty brackets. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if you made a typo when writing this question but you wrote

```js
map.on('click', 'building_footprints_click', addBuildingPop**UP**);
map.off('click', 'building_footprints_click', addBuildingPop**Up**);
```

Notice the difference in case in the name of your function ?

This syntax is correct and it is the one you should use

If the problem was due to the typo I suggest using a linter to avoid this in the future

Comment: Already checked, it still doesn't work. 
I am starting to think it is a problem with mapbox on react.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is such a basic issue on mapbox with react. Try to make a minimal reproduction of your issue on stackblitz and you'll figure out your problem. Or post the stackblitz link here and react people will give you a hand

Comment: Yes, I think is weird too. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5maykf?file=src/App.js